# Print data from database to html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to print data from database to html table. I want my table to be like this:

```
| username | studio APEX | studio CANVAS | studio ORBIT |
+----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+
| Aaron    |       x     |       x       |              |
| Adel     |             |               |       x      |
| John     |       x     |       x       |              |
| James    |       x     |       x       |              |
| Kate     |             |               |       x      |
| Peter    |       x     |               |              |
```

Where studio name is taken from databse. What I got is query:

```
$sql2 = '
            select
              p2.proc_leader as username,
                   max(case when studio = "APEX" then "x" else "" end) as APEX,
                   max(case when studio = "BASECAMP" then "x" else "" end) as BASECAMP,
                   max(case when studio = "CANVAS" then "x" else "" end) as CANVAS,
                   max(case when studio = "HORIZON" then "x" else "" end) as HORIZON,
                   max(case when studio = "LAUNCHPAD" then "x" else "" end) as LAUNCHPAD,
                   max(case when studio = "NEBULA" then "x" else "" end) as NEBULA,
                   max(case when studio = "ORBIT" then "x" else "" end) as ORBIT,
                   max(case when studio = "PALETTE" then "x" else "" end) as PALETTE,
                   max(case when studio = "SANDBOX" then "x" else "" end) as SANDBOX,
                   max(case when studio = "STELLAR" then "x" else "" end) as STELLAR,
                   max(case when studio = "THE CLIMB" then "x" else "" end) as THECLIMB,
                   max(case when studio = "TOONIGAMI" then "x" else "" end) as TOONIGAMI,
                   max(case when studio = "TREEHOUSE" then "x" else "" end) as TREEHOUSE
            from process p1
            left join (
              select *
              from proc_leader
              union all
              select *
              from proc_checker
              union all
              select *
              from proc_staff    
            ) p2 on p1.projectNo = p2.projectNo
            and p1.process = p2.process
            group by p2.proc_leader
';
```

Then I am trying to print to html table:

```
 $query2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

  while ($data2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
    $username = $data2['username'];
    $apex = $data2['APEX'];
    $basecamp = $data2['BASECAMP'];
    $canvas = $data2['CANVAS'];
    $horizon = $data2['HORIZON'];
    $launchpad = $data2['LAUNCHPAD'];
    $nebula = $data2['NEBULA'];
    $orbit = $data2['ORBIT'];
    $palette = $data2['PALETTE'];
    $sandbox = $data2['SANDBOX'];
    $stellar = $data2['STELLAR'];
    $theclimb = $data2['THECLIMB'];
    $toonigame = $data2['TOONIGAMI'];
    $treehouse = $data2['TREEHOUSE'];   

            $header =
                '<th>Username</th>
                <th>Studio'.$apex.'</th>
                <th>Studio'.$basecamp.'</th>
                <th>Studio'.$canvas.'</th>
                <th>Studio'.$horizon.'</th>
                <th>Studio'.$launchpad.'</th>
                <th>Studio'.$nebula.'</th>
                <th>Studio'.$orbit.'</th>
                <th>Studio'.$palette.'</th>
                <th>Studio'.$sandbox.'</th>
                <th>Studio'.$stellar.'</th>
                <th>Studio'.$theclimb.'</th>
                <th>Studio'.$toonigame.'</th>
                <th>Studio'.$treehouse.'</th>';

            //body
            $body = '';
                $row = '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($username) . '</td>';
                $body .= "<tr>$row</tr>";
            echo "<thead>$header</thead><tbody>$body</tbody>";      
}
```

But it seems not working as I want it to. Here is how my table look like now:

```
| username | studiox     | studiox       | studio       |
+----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+
| Aaron    |             |               |              |
| username | studio      | studio        | studiox      |
| Adel     |             |               |              |
| username | studiox     | studiox       | studio       |
| John     |             |               |              |
| username | studiox     | studiox       | studio       |
| James    |             |               |              |
| username | studio      | studio        | studiox      |
| Kate     |             |               |              |
| username | studiox     | studio        | studio       |
| Peter    |             |               |              |
```

What is the problem and can I print table correctly? Thank you

Comment: How about updating the question with rendered HTML? And why echoing the header each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the `while` loop:

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

$header = '<tr><th>Username</th>
            <th>Studio APEX</th>
            <th>Studio BASECAMP</th>
            <th>Studio CANVAS</th>
            <th>Studio HORIZON</th>
            <th>Studio LAUNCHPAD</th>
            <th>Studio NEBULA</th>
            <th>Studio ORBIT</th>
            <th>Studio PALETTE</th>
            <th>Studio SANDBOX</th>
            <th>Studio STELLAR</th>
            <th>Studio THECLIMB</th>
            <th>Studio TOONIGAMI</th>
            <th>Studio TREEHOUSE</th></tr>';
$body = '';
while ($data2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
    $username = $data2['username'];
    $apex = $data2['APEX'];
    $basecamp = $data2['BASECAMP'];
    $canvas = $data2['CANVAS'];
    $horizon = $data2['HORIZON'];
    $launchpad = $data2['LAUNCHPAD'];
    $nebula = $data2['NEBULA'];
    $orbit = $data2['ORBIT'];
    $palette = $data2['PALETTE'];
    $sandbox = $data2['SANDBOX'];
    $stellar = $data2['STELLAR'];
    $theclimb = $data2['THECLIMB'];
    $toonigame = $data2['TOONIGAMI'];
    $treehouse = $data2['TREEHOUSE'];

    $row = '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($username) . '</td>
                <td>' . $apex . '</td>
                <td>' . $basecamp . '</td>
                <td>' . $canvas . '</td>
                <td>' . $horizon . '</td>
                <td>' . $launchpad . '</td>
                <td>' . $nebula . '</td>
                <td>' . $orbit . '</td>
                <td>' . $palette . '</td>
                <td>' . $sandbox . '</td>
                <td>' . $stellar . '</td>
                <td>' . $tdeclimb . '</td>
                <td>' . $toonigame . '</td>
                <td>' . $treehouse . '</td>';
    $body .= '<tr>' . $row . '</tr>';
}
echo '<table><thead>' . $header . '</thead><tbody>' . $body . '</tbody></table>';
```

Just make sure you don't loop the wrong parts. In  you case you only want to build the body of the table in your loop. So build the head before or after you execute the loop, so you only do it once and not in every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are making the table header in loop, so try this:

```
echo '<table>';

// This is table header    
echo '<tr> <th>Column Name 1</th> <th>Column Name 2</th> <th>Column Name 3</th></tr><tbody>';

// This is the table body
foreach( .. )
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$var.'<td>';
    echo '<td>'.$var.'<td>';
    ...
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: what should i put inside `foreach`?

Comment: And your header: `echo '<tr><th>Username</th>
                <th>Studio apex</th>
                <th>Studio basecamp</th>
                <th>Studio canvas</th>
                <th>Studio horizon</th>
                <th>Studio launchpad</th>
                <th>Studio nebula</th>
                <th>Studio orbit</th>
                <th>Studio palette</th>
                <th>Studio sandbox</th>
                <th>Studio stellar</th>
                <th>Studio theclimb</th>
                <th>Studio toonigame</th>
                <th>Studio treehouse</th></tr><tbody>';`

Comment: I meant inside brackets `foreach (?)` Should it be `username`?

Comment: foreach($data as $variable){  } some thing like this

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to think about - although I should stress that I'm no PHP coder...

```
<?php

$my_array = array(
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
    3 => 5,
    4 => 7
);

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
echo $i;
if(in_array($i,$my_array)){echo " yes <br>\n";} else {echo " no <br>\n";}
}

?>
```

Outputs...

```
0 no
1 yes
2 yes
3 yes
4 no
5 yes
6 no
7 yes
8 no
9 no
```